# 数日間の質問制限を受けた時のページが英語のまま

Tags: バグ, 英語

昨日既に２回質問した状況で「質問する」を押した所、次の文章が表示されました。

> You have reached your question limit
>   It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 1 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 3 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.
>
> Recommended reading:
>
> - tips on asking great questions as well as our guidance on
> - which questions are allowed here
>
> Additional advice
>
> - Examining highly-scored questions in the tags that interest you is a great way to study how to ask better questions, that also get better answers much sooner!
> - We don’t demand perfection, but please make sure you use proper grammar, spelling and capitalization, it really helps!
> - Improve downvoted questions rather than deleting them.
> - Do not delete your account, create new accounts, or otherwise attempt to circumvent these restrictions.
> - Do not contact us regarding these restrictions, they cannot be lifted.
>
> Failure to heed this advice may increase the severity of these restrictions.
>
> For more information
>
> See: Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?
>
> It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks seeking answers. Just do your best to make sure you've improved the quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in 3 days!

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited
またここには週に1件とありますが、週に2件の誤りではないのでしょうか？

Comment: 討議でもバグでもないと思うので機能要求が一番な気がします。

Comment: そのページのモバイル版を用意してほしいという要望と、文章が英語のままという問題（これはモデレーターで対応できます）は別投稿にしていただけませんか？

Comment: @Sun-Solar-Arrow オッケー、モバイル版を機能要求として別投稿します。

Answer (score 1):

> ### 質問の投稿が制限されています
>
> **これまでに投稿した質問を振り返りつつ、少し休憩してはいかがでしょうか？**
>
> 最近 $NumQuestions$ 件の質問を投稿されていますが、そのうちいくつかはコミュニティでの評判があまりよくないようです。もちろん誰もが最初から完璧な投稿を書けるわけではありません。ただ結果として、あなたからの質問がブロックされてしまったようです。
>
> 最後に質問されてから $DaysSinceLastQuestion$ 日経っているので、あと $CalculatedLimit$ 日程度でブロックが解除されるはずです。それまで[過去に投稿した質問](/users/current?tab=questions)を見直したり、コメントで指摘された問題があればそれを修正してみてください。
>
> **まずはこちらをお読みください:**
>
> - [良い質問をするには？](/help/how-to-ask)
> - [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](/help/on-topic)
>
> **アドバイス**
>
> - 興味のあるタグで高い評価を得ている質問を読んでみるのも参考になるでしょう。よりよい質問が書けるようになれば、よりよい回答も得やすくなります。
> - 誤字脱字や用語の誤りがなく、読みやすい文章であることも大事なことです。完璧にとは言いませんが、投稿する前に一度読み直してみてください。
> - 低評価を受けた質問は削除するより改善しましょう
> - アカウントを作りなおしたり、その他の方法で制限を回避しようとしないでください。
> - この制限について問い合わせを頂いても、手動で解除することはできません。
>
> これらのアドバイスに反する行動が続く場合、より制限が厳しくなる場合があります。
>
> **その他の参考情報**
>
> 英語ですが、本家 StackOverflow Meta にこの制限についてのQ&Aが用意されています。
>
> [Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543)
>
> ここまでに説明したような点に気を付けて質問を投稿しているうちに、このサイトがどういうシステムで、周りのユーザーが質問者に何を期待しているか、などが理解できることと思います。既存の質問の改善に全力を尽くし、$CalculatedLimit$日後に質問してくれることをお待ちしています！

リンクされているメタ投稿も日本語に訳すといいかもしれませんが、ひとまず上の内容で[Transifexに登録しました](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289949?tags=q2275)。

> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited という記事もあってですね・・・。